# Conditional row count based on two variables (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-science

I have a problem I can't wrap my head around at the moment. I have a large dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame( 
         Marker = c("", "", "", "start_tone", "", "", "start_trial", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "start_tone", "", "", "", "start_trial", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
         size=c(3, NA, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1 , 3.5, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, NA, 4, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.5, -1))

df
```

What I want is to count the number of samples **starting from the "start_trial" marker**. I want that count to go both directions, in negative and positive values. Furthermore, I want that negative count to stop an **n** amount of samples (say 2) before the "start_tone" marker. In the positive direction, I want that count to stop **n** (here 2) samples before the next "start_tone" marker (where the negative count starts). Lastly, I want a new column that keeps track of the trials around each "start_trial" marker. So, it should look something like the following:

```
df2 <- data.frame(SampleCount = c("", -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
         Marker = c("", "", "", "start_tone", "", "", "start_trial", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "start_tone", "", "", "", "start_trial", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
         size=c(3, NA, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1 , 3.5, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, NA, 4, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4.5, -1),
         trial=c("", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial 1", "trial1", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2", "trial 2" ))

df2
```

Thanks a lot for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cumsum` and `lead` to create the groups, and then use `row_number` to create the sample count:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(trial = cumsum(lead(Marker, 2, default = "") == "start_tone")) %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(any(Marker == "start_trial"), row_number()[Marker == "start_trial"], NA),
         sampleCount = row_number() - n)
```

output

```r
   Marker         size trial     n sampleCount
   <chr>         <dbl> <int> <int>       <int>
 1 ""              3       0    NA          NA
 2 ""             NA       1     6          -5
 3 ""             -1       1     6          -4
 4 "start_tone"   -1       1     6          -3
 5 ""              4       1     6          -2
 6 ""             -1       1     6          -1
 7 "start_trial"  -1       1     6           0
 8 ""              3.5     1     6           1
 9 ""             -1       1     6           2
10 ""             -1       1     6           3
11 ""              4       1     6           4
12 ""             -1       1     6           5
13 ""             -1       2     7          -6
14 ""             NA       2     7          -5
15 "start_tone"    4       2     7          -4
16 ""             -1       2     7          -3
17 ""             -1       2     7          -2
18 ""              2       2     7          -1
19 "start_trial"  -1       2     7           0
20 ""             -1       2     7           1
21 ""             -1       2     7           2
22 ""             -1       2     7           3
23 ""             -1       2     7           4
24 ""              4.5     2     7           5
25 ""             -1       2     7           6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for the dataframe I posted, but there is an additional problem I didn't think of that is causing problems when using this solution. The start of the dataframe actually has hundreds of rows before the first "start_tone". So when I run this solution it gives me the following error message: Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `sampleCount = row_number() - row_number()[Marker == "onset_trial"]`.
x `sampleCount` must be size 184 or 1, not 0.

Comment: Can you update the question and reproduce the error?

Comment: I've updated the dataframe, so now it should give the error.

Comment: I believe the issue is related to `row_number()[Marker == "onset_trial"]` where in the first group before the first start_tone there are no rows with `Marker` of onset_trial...

Comment: Answer updated. It should work now.